# Graph examination (complete, bipartite, Eulerian, number of connected components, tree / forest)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have this graph,

[image: graph]

and I need to answer some questions like:

1. *This graph is complete?*
2. *This graph is Eulerian?*
3. *This graph is Bipartite?*
4. *This graph is a Tree or a Forest?*
5. *How many connected components have?*

I think:

1. No because $E \neq V\times V$
2. No, because vertices f and d have an odd degree
3. No, because there is a circuit(cycle) of an odd length (like a, g, b, a or g, d, b, g, ...)
4. No, neither a tree nor a forest, Is not a tree because $|V| \neq |E|-1$
5. Just one, the graph itself

Are my ideas right? can you give me some advice?

Comment: All of your answers are correct. For a couple you could give simpler reasons: it’s not complete because, for instance, there is no edge $ge$, and it’s not a forest or tree because it contains the cycle $def$ (among others).

Comment: No to pick a nit, but the edges of a complete graph are not $V\times V$, since that would give a loop at each vertex.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for the criticism